# Unable to bring button at the center of span

Tags: html, user-interface

I'm working on UI part on my project and want to bring button at the center of span tag,

I tried with text-align: center but it's not working that way
can anyone please guide how I can bring it to center.

I tried with text-align: center, also tried to keep it outside div but it's not working that way
Please if anyone guide how I can fix this.

```css
button{
text-align:center;


}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
Inventory Page
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Last modified Date</th>
    <div>
<span>
<button> test </button>
</span>
</div>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Modified by</td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    
  </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: like that span is place in an invalid place and seems to not have width. Do you define a width somewhere for your span ?

Comment: moreover text-align is just to place text not div or span element. Where to you want to place the span ? inside the table ? outside ?

Comment: The button **is** in the centre of the span. It's just that the span is *the same size as the button*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could set the display on button to block and then add margin:0 auto but a better way is to use flex.  set the display on the div surrounding the button to flex and add justify-content:center

```css
#button {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: solid 1px red;
  display: block;
}

#container{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  Inventory Page
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Last modified Date</th>
      <div >

        <button id='button'> test </button>

      </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Modified by</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>

    </tr>
  </table>
  
  Inventory Page
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Last modified Date</th>
      <div id='container'>

        <button > test </button>

      </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Modified by</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>

    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

In this code, a wrapper div element with the class "center" is added around the button. The CSS class "center" uses display: flex and justify-content: center to horizontally center the contents of the div, which includes the button.

CSS:

```
.center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<button class="center">test</button>
```